# TYPO3 write rights for which system user

Tags: typo3, windows-server-2019, typo3-10.x

I have installed TYPO3 v10 from scratch for a testing environment.
But I can't start the install tool. I always get `Oops, an error occurred!`

Maybe it is a question of enable write rights for `typo3temp` and so on.
I have searched the Internet now for hours, but I can not find any specification, for which Windows Server 2019 user I have to enable the write function.
Is it system, trusted installer or what ever?

Comment: I suspect you missed somehow the tutorial [Getting started](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/10.4/en-us/Index.html#start)

Comment: More documents you can find on this page: https://docs.typo3.org/

Comment: btw. the user for the TYPO3 is at best always the web-server-user. It's not the user of the operating-system!!! Some configure only the group of the webserver but that's not advisable. So the webserver-user is usually also owner of all folders and files in the installation.

Comment: Did you follow the [Trouble Shooting](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/master/en-us/Troubleshooting/Index.html) page? The log files under typo3temp/var/log/ will give you the details about the error.

Comment: @David your documents you mentioned, doesn't tell me, which user I have to use. Under MS Server the user IIS_IUSRS which is the user which access the server from the internet and for security reasons this user should not have any rights for changing or writing.

Comment: @Franz, for using the trouble shooting page, I have to get into the Amin Tool, what not is working.

Comment: No, you only need to edit the file typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php and make adaptions accordiing to [Debugging and development setup](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/ErrorAndExceptionHandling/Examples/Index.html#error-handling-configuration-examples-debug).

Comment: As I'm not working with MS Server I can't tell you to to handle specific settings there. I can only tell you how it's usually done. You're free to create a user for a special file-directory of a whole TYPO3-installation and grant that user all rights but only on that directory recursive. Consider that you have to adjust FTP-user and -rights then perhaps too.